# Youtube Autoplay on mobile not working but in browser it works

Tags: php, youtube, autoplay

i just embed regular youtube video into my html file.
and i use autoplay=1  ,and it works regulary on browsers.
but the autoplay doesn't work with any mobile.

can you help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`

```js
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'controls': 0,
            'autohide': 1,
            'wmode': 'opaque',
            'showinfo': 0,
            'loop': 1,
     'playlist': 'aF5HAF0fg6M',
     'fs':1
        },
        videoId: 'aF5HAF0fg6M',
        events: {
            'onReady': function(){
      player.pauseVideo();
      player.playVideo();
     }
        }
    });

}

window.onload=function() {
};
```

```css
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<div class="video-background">
<div class="video-foreground">
 <div id="player" ></div>
</div>
</div>

<div>test</div>
```

Working sample on the following link
http://demo.jawadsolutions.com/researchs/youtube/